# Is it possbile to override an exisiting field in the mapping of an index by having a runtime field with the same name?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, spring-data-elasticsearch

Override field values at query time in elastic search

On a high level, we know that we can use runtime fields to generate new fields to be used before and after the search results.

Also, when we specify the name of the runtime field in the search query under fields object, we get the runtime field with the original mapping field in the response.

For example suppose, the below search query with runtime field returns

```
​​GET runtime_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "times_average": {
      "type": "double",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit((doc['participations.race1.time_secs'].value + doc['participations.race2.time_secs'].value + doc['participations.race3.time_secs'].value)/3);"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

RESULT

```
{
_source : {
"times_average " : "test1"
},
fields : [
{times_average : "somevalue"}
]
}
```

I want to get the times_average field inside the _source, and if possible override an existing times_average field already present in the original mapping.

Is this possible ?

Tried using same name but did not work

Comment: What did you try (code)? what did not work? Which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use?